Counterexample of projection game
Consider projection name $H$ with projection function $\sigma$ with $val(H)\in [0.1,0.9]$, how to construct a $H$ s.t. $val(H^{\otimes 2})\geq val(H)-\epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$?
There is a famous counterexample that is odd cycle game, however it has value $1-1/2n$, which dosen't satisfy $val(H)\leq 0.9$. I want to lower the value of odd cycle game but find it difficult.

Please [edit] your post to provide more context.  What is "projection game" and "odd cycle game"?  Please define what is a "projection", "projection name", "projection function", and what is the definition of $val$.  It seems like you might be reusing the same name $H$ for multiple purposes.  A statement like "given $H$, construct $H$ such that..." makes no sense, as $H$ is already been given and cannot be changed.  Please [edit] your post to make it clearer what you are asking.
